# Remove all characters after the first occurring integer

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-replace, truncation

I need to remove everything after the first occurrence of a number in a string, but the number must remain. I'm having trouble keeping the number when I write this:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9].*/', '', $string);
```

It removes everything including the number.

Comment: What is in the `$string`?

Comment: it's a hebrew string with numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your first replacement already works but removes too much, you can capture the number and put it back in:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]+).*/', '$1', $string); 
               ^      ^       ^^ put the captured value back
```

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop, try using `mb_substr($string, $i, 1)` to get the character instead of `$string[$i]`. I think the latter only returns the single byte at byte index $i instead of the number $i character of a string with multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
$str = "abc123efg567jjjj";
echo preg_replace("/([^0-9]*[0-9]*)(.*)/", "$1", $str);
```

Sample output:

```
abc123
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need capture groups or backreferences.  Just forget the digits with `\K` after matching them.  The `.*` will match the rest of the string and only this part will be removed.

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/\d+\K.*/', '', $string);
```